# Set JavaFX PieChart label color via css

Tags: java, javafx, pie-chart

I have a PieChart in my Java application which looks just like this:

[image: PieChartFullImage]

A picture of a label (very hard to see):

[image: The Label]

Since the pie chart is rendered on a solid gray background, (which is basically the same color as the labels' text) the labels are virtually invisible. So, my question is, **is there any CSS code that would change the color of a PieChart label's text, and if so, what is it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any future users below is answer with css code:

You can find more here : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm

```
.chart-pie-label-line {
    -fx-stroke: #8b4513;
    -fx-fill: #8b4513;
}

.chart-pie-label { /*this is what you need for labels*/
    -fx-fill: #8b4513;
    -fx-font-size: 1em;
} 
.chart-legend {
   -fx-background-color:  #fafad2;
   -fx-stroke: #daa520;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So, the labels of a pie chart are `Text` objects, meaning that the CSS property `-fx-text-fill` does not work for them. Instead, the `-fx-fill` property changes their color.

Here is a screenshot of my Pie Chart with colored labels:

[image: Colored Pie Chart]

A simple line of CSS does the trick...

```
.chart-pie-label {-fx-fill: #ff4f0a;}
```

Comment: Can you please add the css code , then you can accept your answer .

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS Sure thing.

Comment: Now it's better .